# Making a PC race that is ridable?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, races, mount

I've got a world I'm making with unique races that I'll be using to play with close friends that would like to be able to cooperate with each other more in game.

I definitely am leaning towards making a specific race that is actually mountable, but I was wondering if there were any inherent gameplay/mechanical problems presented by doing this?

The easiest example of an issue I could see is size related issues (Medium vs. Large), but I was thinking that this race is a sizable Medium-sized race, large enough one humanoid can ride atop it but no more. If I'm not mistakened Large creatures are suppose to take up 2x2 squares, so I was going to make this a creature that could take up 1x2 and define the "criteria" for large 2x2 if any players had questions regarding this.

Comment: What exactly is your question? I see one sentence with a question mark (“Are there any inherent problems with this?”) but it's not clear what actual problem(s) that is asking about, whether social, mechanical, believable, design, idea, etc. or what.

Comment: I meant mechanical, I'll clarify that now

Comment: The core question is still not clear.  The title question: Make sure you identify it as a PC race, since some DM creations are DM / NPC only.  Secondly, it appears that you are asking whether or not there are mechanical problems with a medium race riding a medium race.  Is that your core question?

Comment: Read a couple more questions do you can get an idea of how specific you need to make it. This is very unclear

Comment: Well I'm not as much concerned about a medium race riding a medium mount as much as how a medium mount changes the actual mechanics of things your mount can do.

Comment: So then is your question really "how would a Medium mount differ from a Large mount?"

Comment: Yeah, I also have questions regarding turn/movement related issues but can ask that in another question.